# Pushing and popping the first element of a std::tuple

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I am writing a function in C++ with a variable number of arguments (and different types) in this way

```
template<typename ...Ts>
void myFunction(Ts ...args)
{
    //create std::tuple to access and manipulate single elements of the pack
    auto myTuple = std::make_tuple(args...);    

    //do stuff

    return;
}
```

What i would like to do, but I don't know how, is to push and pop elements from the tuple, in particular the first element... something like

```
//remove the first element of the tuple thereby decreasing its size by one
myTuple.pop_front()

//add addThis as the first element of the tuple thereby increasing its size by one
myTuple.push_front(addThis)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: yes, but not as member functions.

Comment: Its size is a compile-time property (the length of the template parameter list). You can't reuse the same type.

Comment: @Jarod42 Then how? What functions should I use?

Comment: Look at [std::tuple_cat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/tuple_cat/).

Comment: The new element (`addThis`) you want to insert in the first position is the same or is another element? In the second case the type of the new element is a different type?

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks, that way I suppose I can create a new tuple by concatenating a tuple with only the element I want to add with the old one and then renaming it myTuple. But what about creating one without the first element of the old one?

Comment: @BiagioFesta The new element is different and, in principle, of any type, even different from the types that are in the tuple. In practice my tuple will have only ints, doubles and chars and the new element to insert will be one of this types.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may do something like

```
template <typename T, typename Tuple>
auto push_front(const T& t, const Tuple& tuple)
{
    return std::tuple_cat(std::make_tuple(t), tuple);
}

template <typename Tuple, std::size_t ... Is>
auto pop_front_impl(const Tuple& tuple, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return std::make_tuple(std::get<1 + Is>(tuple)...);
}

template <typename Tuple>
auto pop_front(const Tuple& tuple)
{
    return pop_front_impl(tuple,
                          std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value - 1>());
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/dtc1fQ)

Note that it is really basic and doesn't handle tuple of reference, or tuple of const qualified type, but it might be sufficient.

Comment: you've missed a `return` in the `pop_front_impl`, I suppose

Comment: Thnk you, but when I try to compile (visual studio) it says: C4430 missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Comment: Demo link added. Your version of MSVC might not support auto deduced type: you can try to add `-> decltype(std::tuple_cat(std::make_tuple(t), tuple))` just before code block.

Comment: @BiagioFesta: Yes, typos fixed, and Demo link added.

Comment: @Jarod42 Strange... I have 2015 community version. But since your demo works it's something on my side. You've helped me a lot, ty.

Answer (score 3):

With generic lambdas, you can do quite elegant:

```
template<typename Tuple>
constexpr auto pop_front(Tuple tuple) {
    static_assert(std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value > 0, "Cannot pop from an empty tuple");
    return std::apply(
        [](auto, auto... rest) { return std::make_tuple(rest...); }, 
        tuple);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Length and types of a `std::tuple` are determined at compile time. No run-time popping or pushing is possible. You could use a `std::vector` to provide for the run-time modifications.

The data type for your vector could be a `std::variant` (C++17) or `boost::variant`. Both types take a list of supported types at compile time, and can be filled with any value of matching type.

Alternatively, you could use `std::any` (also C++17) or `boost::any` to store *any* type, but with different access semantics.

```
typedef boost::variant<int, std::string, double> value;
std::vector<value> data;
data.push_back(value(42));
data.psuh_back(value(3.14));
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot 'lengthen' the tuple by adding elements - that is not what a tuple represents. The point of a tuple is the binding connection between the different values that make it up, like 'firstname', 'lastname', 'phone'.

What you seem to want is much easier accomplished by using a vector - you can easily add elements to it, and remove them - its size can be arbitrarily changed as needed.

Comment: All elements in a vector must be the same type though, unlike the constituents of OP's tuple

Comment: But with a vector I cannot have different variable types.

Comment: you can make a vector of `void*`, and store their addresses. Otherwise, there is little to be done, a list of an _unknown_ amount of _unknown_ differing types? What do you expect, _black magic_?

Comment: A list of an unknown number of unknown differing types could be `std::vector<std::any>` as long as you work with the interface.