# C++17: pass multiple callable objects together with their parameters

Tags: c++, c++17, callable, variadic

I would like to write a function (C++17 if that matters) that accepts multiple callable objects together with their arguments and executes them in a loop. I would also like to avoid any intermediate copying of data.

Example:

Assume we have three functions `f0`, `f1` and `f2` that expect different number of input parameters

```cpp
void f0() {
 // Implementation of f0
}
void f1(int a) { 
 // Implementation of f1
}
void f2(int a, int b) {
 // Implementation of f2
}
```

I'm looking for a way to pass all functions above together with sample input arguments into class or another function (say `Execute`). A sample interface would look like following:

```cpp
int main() {
  // If Execute is a class
  Execute exec({f0}, {f1, 4}, {f2, 1, 2});

  // The result of the command above is a sequence of calls
  // 1. f0()
  // 2. f1(4)
  // 3. f2(1, 2)
}
```

I would like to avoid any intermediate copying of data.

So my question how would one achieve that?

Comment: Seems like a work for [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)and related [utility functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility#Pairs_and_tuples).

Comment: Trying to get something workable right at the moment. Just would like to mention that I do not need neither want a tuple to construct anything. Not sure if I manage to

Comment: @TruLa: `std::forward_as_tuple` would presumably be the basis for avoiding intermediate copies. I'm not familiar enough with the stuff needed to get this working, but if the functions were passed separately from their arguments, all using universal references, with the arguments passed via `std::forward_as_tuple`, you'd avoid copies, and `std::apply` (with `std::forward` involved as applicable) is designed to invoke an arbitrary callable with an existing tuple of arguments.

Comment: Please also show how `Execute` is going to use the passed-in objects. It is ok that you make up something how the functions are stored, but you should show how exactly the functions are then going to be called.

Comment: @j6t `Execute` does not need to know anything about callables or arguments passed, neither it needs to store anything inside. I'm not exactly sure how I can show the usage but the idea is that the code simply translates into a sequence of calls `f0(); f1(4); f2(1, 2)`. None of the parameters has to be stored.

Comment: Posted my attempt to solve a problem as an answer below

Comment: Do you need tuples, versus just capturing lambdas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For completeness, here's a zero effort solution.

```
template <typename... T> 
void execute (T&&... t)
{
    (t(),...);
}

int main()
{
    int a = 42, b = 0;
    // this
    execute([&](){f0();}, [&](){f1(a);}, [&](){f2(a,b);});
    // or this
    execute(std::bind(f0), std::bind(f1, a), std::bind(f2, a, b));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, makes perfect sense. Essentially reducing a problem of a function with non-zero parameters to the function with zero parameters. Although the solution is based on the same principles as mine, I accept your solution as it answers exactly the original question with minimum amount of code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working solution that implements a templated class using `std::tuple` that imitates what you suggested.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

void f0() {
    std::cout << "f0\n";
}

void f1(int a) {
    std::cout << "f1: " << a << '\n';
}

void f2(int a, int b) {
    std::cout << "f2: " << a + b << '\n';
}

void f3(const std::string a, int b) {
    std::cout << "f3: " << a << " ** " << b << '\n';
}

template <typename T1, typename... Ts>
std::tuple<Ts...> unshift_tuple(const std::tuple<T1, Ts...>& tuple)
noexcept
{
    return std::apply(
        [](auto&&, const auto&... args) {
            return std::tie(args...);
        },
        tuple
    );
}

template <typename Callable, typename... Params>
void call(const std::tuple<Callable, Params...>& t) noexcept {
    const auto f = std::get<0>(t); 
    const auto args = unshift_tuple(t);
    std::apply(f, args);
}

template <typename... Params>
class Execute {
public:
    Execute(std::tuple<Params...>&& t) : m_fs(t) { }
    
    void execute() noexcept {
        iterate_over_functions<0>(m_fs);
    }
    
private:
    template <std::size_t I, typename... Ts>
    void iterate_over_functions(const std::tuple<Ts...>& t) noexcept {
        if constexpr (I < sizeof...(Ts)) {
            call(std::get<I>(t));
            iterate_over_functions<I + 1>(t);
        }
    }
    
private:
    std::tuple<Params...> m_fs;
};

int main() {
    Execute f(
        std::make_tuple(
            std::make_tuple(f0),
            std::make_tuple(f1, 1),
            std::make_tuple(f2, 1, 2),
            std::make_tuple(f3, "Stack Overflow!", 2)
        )
    );
    
    f.execute();
}
```

Note: I needed to [remember](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53504272/12075306) how to unshift a tuple and call a function using as arguments the values in a `std::tuple` using `std::apply`.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following solution.
Can anyone please tell me if it is a valid one?

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

void f0() {
  std::cout << "f0:" << std::endl;
}

void f1(int a) {
  std::cout << "f1: " << a << std::endl;
}

void f2(int a, int b) {
  std::cout << "f2: " << a << "," << b << std::endl;
}

template <typename... Tuples>
void execute(Tuples &&... tuples) {
  (std::apply(std::get<0>(tuples), std::get<1>(tuples)), ...);
}

int main() {
  execute(std::forward_as_tuple(f0, std::forward_as_tuple()),
          std::forward_as_tuple(f1, std::forward_as_tuple(1)),
          std::forward_as_tuple(f2, std::forward_as_tuple(3, 4)));
}
```